# How to start and stop a task using at command?

Tags: downloads, cron, scheduled

I want to start download using `aria2c` everyday at 02:00 am and stop it at 08:00 am.

I know I should use

```
at 02:00 
at>aria2c ....
```

I don't know how to tell 'at' to stop it! Actually aria2c stops downloading with Ctrl+C and I don't know how to tell this to 'at'!

And when aria2c starts downloading at the given time, it runs at the backgrounds and I don't know how to stop it manually either!

Any suggestions?

By the way, is there any way to do this automatically? I mean create some sort of scheduled task to do it every day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pkill` to kill a process:

`pkill aria2c`

Of course, you can schedule the killing with `at` the same way you do the launch.

Comment: thanks that works fine. but is there a way to tell at to run aria2c  at the foreground?

Comment: Use `screen`, a text screen manager. To start the program in background: `screen -d -m <command>`, then use `screen -r` to reconnect and Ctrl+A D to detach. See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/screen.1.html